# ImportError: No module named tinyec.registry

Tags: python, module

`>>>"ImportError: No module named tinyec.registry"`

I try to install [pupy](https://github.com/n1nj4sec/pupy/wiki). I install all dependencies but there is one left.

#./pupysh.py

```
2020-07-13 16:52:12,987| Datagram based stream is not available: KCP missing                                                                                                                   
2020-07-13 16:52:13,011| No module named http_parser.pyparser: socks module disabled, auto_connect unavailable                                                                                 
2020-07-13 16:52:13,016| Transport rsa_aes disabled: No module named **tinyec.registry**                                                                                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                             
  File "/home/art/osint/pupy/pupy/network/lib/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>                                                                                                               
    from .transports.rsa_aes import RSA_AESClient, RSA_AESServer                                                                                                                               
  File "/home/art/osint/pupy/pupy/network/lib/transports/rsa_aes.py", line 14, in <module>                                                                                                     
    from cryptoutils import get_random, NewAESCipher                                                                                                                                           
  File "/home/art/osint/pupy/pupy/network/lib/transports/cryptoutils/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>                                                                                        
    from .ecpv import ECPV                                                                                                                                                                     
  File "/home/art/osint/pupy/pupy/network/lib/transports/cryptoutils/ecpv.py", line 10, in <module>                                                                                            
    from tinyec.registry import get_curve                                                                                                                                                      
ImportError: No module named tinyec.registry                                                                                                                                                   
2020-07-13 16:52:13,017| Transport ec4 disabled: No module named tinyec.registry                                                                                                               
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                             
  File "/home/art/osint/pupy/pupy/network/lib/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>                                                                                                               
    from .transports.ec4 import EC4TransportServer, EC4TransportClient                                                                                                                         
  File "/home/art/osint/pupy/pupy/network/lib/transports/ec4.py", line 8, in <module>                                                                                                          
    from .cryptoutils import RC4, SHA384, ECPV                                                                                                                                                 
  File "/home/art/osint/pupy/pupy/network/lib/transports/cryptoutils/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>                                                                                        
    from .ecpv import ECPV                                                                                                                                                                     
  File "/home/art/osint/pupy/pupy/network/lib/transports/cryptoutils/ecpv.py", line 10, in <module>                                                                                            
    from tinyec.registry import get_curve
```

However :`

- pip install tinyec: ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tinyec
- sys.path: ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/

Idea, what's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is a better chance that you will get a high quality answer if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

> I think you can try installing   'tinyec.registry' separately